# как подключить mpl_interactions к mplfinance в pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, matplotlib

нужно реализовать функции panhandler, zoom_factory из mpl-interactions. для panhandler нужен figure, а для zoom_factory axes. сложность возникла в том, что график mplfinance внедряется в pyqt интерфейс, и невозможно получить figure и axes через mpf.plot(). но удалость получить эти две переменные через создание собственной фигуры и axes-а. это сработало на таком примере:

```
import mplfinance as mpf

from mpl_interactions import ioff, panhandler, zoom_factory

with ioff:
        fig = mpf.figure(style='yahoo',figsize=(7,8))
        ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)

mpf.plot(data.tail(20),ax=ax)


pan_handler = panhandler(fig)
disconnect_zoom = zoom_factory(ax)
mpf.show()
```

но даже без mpf.show() переменные fig и ax имеют корректные данные, ну и при запуске все работает отлично.

попробовав тоже самое но уже в классе pyqt у меня получилось отображать графи и при передачи аргументов заработала функция zoom_factory, panhandler не работает, хотя и никаких ошибок не возвращает. вот как я это реализовал:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

        """какой-то код"""

    with ioff:
        fig = mpf.figure(style=self.s)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
        
    mpf.plot(daily.tail(20), type='candle', mav=(3),
     style=self.s, warn_too_much_data=1000, ax=ax)
        
    pan_handler = panhandler(fig)
    disconnect_zoom = zoom_factory(ax)
        
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        
    self.ui.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.toolbar)
    self.ui.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.canvas)
```

в чем может заключаться проблема? хотя и в первом и во втором случае fig имеет одно и тоже значение: Figure(640x480). как правильно получить или передавать fig?